# error no se puede convertir implicitamente una variable de tipo string a objeto?

Tags: c#, c#-8.0

hola buenas tengo una consulta, ee estaba haciendo un proyecto donde debia meter objetos a un arreglo, pero pasa que ahora debe sacar ciertos datos de esos objetos para ingresarlos a un nuevo objeto pero c# no me lo permite, entonces no logro entender de que forma puedo ingresar datos ya existentes de un arreglo de objetos a otro ?, a pesar de ingresar los datos correctamente de esta forma.

```
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el nombre del cliente :");
            objetoCliente.Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el primer apellido :");
            objetoCliente.PrimerApellido = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el segundo apellido :");
            objetoCliente.SegundoApellido = Console.ReadLine();
            clientes[i] = objetoCliente;
```

pero ahora que intento sacar datos de un objeto en especifico de este mismo arreglo veo que no me lo permite a pesar de hacerlo de esta forma, busco el cliente y al buscarlos mando esos datos a una clase donde esos datos son string como lo eran originalmente los principales

```
           public void buscarCliente(string IdCliente)
    {
        
        for (int i = 0; i < clientes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (clientes[i]!= null && IdCliente == clientes[i].Identificador)
            {
                objetoafiliacionclientese.Identificador = clientes[i].Identificador;
                objetoafiliacionclientese.Nombre = clientes[i].Nombre;
                objetoafiliacionclientese.PrimerApellido = clientes[i].PrimerApellido;
                objetoafiliacionclientese.SegundoApellido = clientes[i].SegundoApellido;
           }
          }
          }
```

pero luego cuando en mi otro metodo llamo al objeto (objetoafiliacionclientesede), y llamo a esos datos para meterlos en el objeto de esa clase y volverlos a ingresar a un nuevo arreglo no me lo permite, pero no entiendo que pasa ? esta es otra clase adicional a los 2 codigos anteriores que les enceñe que pertencen a otras clases.

```
          for (int i = contador; i <afiliacionclientesede.Length; i++)
        {
       
            objetoafiliacionclientese = new AfiliacionClienteSede();
            
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Registrar Sedes de clientes");
            Console.WriteLine("Digite la identificacion del cliente de la lista :");
            idCliente = Console.ReadLine();
  
            registroCliente.buscarCliente(idCliente);
       }
```

e intentado ingresar los datos que ya saque del arreglo viejo al nuevo asi

```
        afiliacionclientesede[i] = objetoafiliacionclientese.Identificador;
```

asi

```
       afiliacionclientesede[i].Identificador = objetoafiliacionclientese.Identificador;
```

pero ningun metodo me funciona porque dice que los datos no pueden convertirse implicitamente de tal variable a tal, pero como les mostre inicialmente si lo hacia de esa forma, pero ahora nose porque no me los acepta, podrian por favor ayudarme, se los agradecia demasiado ya que e googleado mucho y no encuentro nada, lo mas que logre intender fue que
**c# e al declarar un tipo de variable esa variable queda como constante, y su dato no puede modificarse, pero entonces nose como podria ingresar los nuevos datos que saque del arreglo de objetos viejo al nuevo**

Comment: No sé si soy solo yo pero no entendí nada de tu pregunta. ¿Dónde obtienes el error? ¿Qué error es? ¿Cuál es el propósito de tu código?

Comment: aariba lo explique .  no logro entender de que forma puedo ingresar datos ya existentes de un arreglo de objetos a otro , esa era la consulta que buscaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez estés declarando mal las variables unciales del arreglo de tu objeto.
También veo que tienes una manera peculiar para insertarle datos al arreglo.

Por lo que puedes hacer uso del append como método para ingresar la información al arreglo. Algo como:

```
Cliente[] clientes = new Cliente[20];

Cliente newCliente = new Cliente();

clientes.Append(newCliente);
```

Si necesitas sacar la información de los clientes que tienes en el arreglo y pasar esa información a otro arreglo, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
Puedes omitir las 3 primeras secciones del código a continuación, solo se hicieron para mostrarte un ejemplo. Lee los comentarios dentro del codigo.

```
//Creación de arreglos
Cliente[] clientes = new Cliente[20];
Cliente[] clientesNuevos = new Cliente[20];

//Ingreso de datos, esto es solo para el ejemplo
Cliente newCliente = new Cliente() { Name = "Daniel"};
Cliente newCliente2 = new Cliente() { Name = "Pedro" };
Cliente newCliente3 = new Cliente() { Name = "Marcos" };
Cliente newCliente4 = new Cliente() { Name = "José" };

clientes.Append(newCliente);
clientes.Append(newCliente2);
clientes.Append(newCliente3);
clientes.Append(newCliente4);


//Lo que necesitas
foreach (var lst in clientes) 
{
    //Imaginemos que deseas la información del cliente Daniel
    //Validamos, creamos un objeto nuevo, le agregamos los valores del cliente
    //guardado al nuevo objeto y este lo guardas en tu nuevo arreglo.
    if (lst.Name == "Daniel") 
    {
        Cliente newClient = new Cliente();
        newClient.Name = lst.Name;

        clientesNuevos.Append(newClient);
    }          
}
```

Comment: hola @Marcos Guerrero gracias la verdad esta forma no la conocia sinceramente, por eso me hacia volas con la forma que yo conosco, pero una consulta y si luego saco datos de ese arreglo y quiero ingresarlos a otro, tendria que hacer una clase exclusiva para esos nuevos datos, y luego insertar el objeto de esa forma ?

Comment: @melaniavecedo he actualizado la respuesta, en respuesta a lo que solicitas, espero te ayude. Lo que hice fue crear una clase cliente para la explicación, esta la cree con un atributo llamado Name, ya en su caso agregaría los demás atributos que necesite.